# Function dblink copy and insert into another database

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, function

I have a problem to insert those fields in another database, how can I make a connection to the other database?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.replica_voh(
    p_id_usuario integer,
    p_apellido_p character,
    p_apellido_m character,
    p_nombre character,
    p_clave character,
    p_puesto character varying,
    p_sucursal integer,
    p_permitir character varying,
    p_usuario character)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
/* Esta Funcion Regresa lo siguente: 
  0  Si todas las operaciones fueron exitosas   
*/
DECLARE
    vUsuario integer;
BEGIN  
    SELECT id_usuario into vUsuario from acc_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = $user;
   -- SELECT * dblink('dbname=dbname port=5432 host=10.*.**.* user=123456 password=098765',
--'SELECT * FROM acc_usuarios where id_usuario=4230')
    IF NOT FOUND THEN    
       INSERT INTO acc_usuarios (id_usuario,apellido_p,apellido_m,nombre,clave,pregunta_s,respuesta_s,estado,perfil,puesto,sucursal,
       permitir,nivel,usuario) 
       VALUES(p_id_usuario,p_apellido_p,p_apellido_m,p_nombre,p_clave,' ',' ','A','N',p_puesto,p_sucursal,p_permitir,'U',p_usuario);   
    END IF;
    return 0;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.replica_voh(integer, character, character, character, character, character varying, integer, character varying, character)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: insert into in another database help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using Postgres instead of MySQL

dblink

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/dblink.html

and

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/contrib-dblink-exec.html

more specifically.